# add class to hightlight input box border if it's empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, kendo-ui

i know it duplicate but solutions from SO is not helped me.

so for

```
<input id="hereMyDropDownValue" />
```

ts:

```
 this.mySQLRespData = d; //here am loading data into kendoDropDown

$("#hereMyDropDownValue").keyup(function(){
                    var respData = $(this);
                    if(respData. val() == ""){
                      respData.addClass("highlight")
                    } else {
                      respData.removeClass("highlight")
                    }
                }); 
$("#hereMyDropDownValue").kendoComboBox({                   
    dataSource: {
       d : this.mySQLRespData 
    },
    value:serialID,    
});
```

css

```
.highlight{
 border-color:red;
}
```

i want to highlight the input box when user delete/backspace the already loaded data.

issue is does not highlight the box border when it becomes empty. I am using kendo drop down.

Comment: `respData. val()` remove space

Comment: @guradio. updated as you said. no luck and also it gives Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null :(

Comment: check it out .its working https://jsfiddle.net/ayatrahmani/mr4g2v4o/1/

Comment: @AyatullahRahmani OMG in fiddle my code is working. y its not supporting in my app

Comment: what error show in console in your app?  put your  code in **$(document).ready(function() { ...})**

Comment: @AyatullahRahmani could you pls check my updated code

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to enclose with `$(function(){ });`.And also you need to change `.on('keyup'` from `.keyup` function. keyup function won't work for dynamic DOM.

```js
$(function() {
 var serialID='';
  $("#hereMyDropDownValue").on('keyup', function() {
    var respData = $(this);
    if (respData.val() == "") {
      respData.addClass("highlight")
    } else {
      respData.removeClass("highlight")
    }
  });

/*$("#hereMyDropDownValue").kendoComboBox({                   
dataSource: {
   d : this.mySQLRespData 
},
value:serialID,    
});*/
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.material.min.css"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>-->
<input id="hereMyDropDownValue" />
```

Comment: did you check this? @fruity

Comment: in fiddle my code is working. y its not supporting in my app

Comment: yeah i checked it but dont know why its not working in my app

Comment: if the DOM is dynamic you need to use `.on('keyup' `  not `.keyup`..I updated.check now @fruity

Comment: can you just share the kendoComboBox cdn which you used?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.621/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

Comment: There is an error in the kendoComboBox cdn script which you given.if i add it shows script error. @fruity

Comment: no man that's not problem actually.. i copied and paste it from official site of telerik

Answer (score 0):

When jQuery look for the #hereMyDropDownValue element, maybe it is not in the DOM. You should be sure to look for it after ajax loading is complete.

Comment: as you said , just waited till service has complete. after that also no luck. i think since am using Kendo ui its doing some conflicts

Comment: Please try to console.log($("#hereMyDropDownValue").length) just before the jQuery on(), and see if it is > 0.